# why classnameA::classnameA::variable in c++ working?

Tags: c++

Recently, I found that below code is working, but I don't understand why.
Why can the compiler use `classNameA::classNameA::variable` to find the variable, but why not `namespaceB::namespaceB::variable`?

```
namespace Cool  
{  
    int a = 5;  
}

class Good    
{  
public:  
    const static int b = 10;  
};

int main()  
{  
    //std::cout << Cool::Cool::a <<std::endl; //why this line not working?  
    std::cout << Good::Good::Good::b << std::endl; // why can the compiler find the variable b?  
    return 0;   
}
```